# FCM token generated is null, may be some conflict with dependencies used

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Initially when I created project for android app, FCM was integrated successfuly and I was able to receive FCM token. But when I added more functionalities and dependencies in my project, I am getting FCM token as null. 
Following is my view of dependencies used

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'

    }    
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0')
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-script:v1-rev6-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.1.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.4'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'me.spark:submitbutton:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
}
```

This is my MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        Log.d(TAG,"Entered MyFirebaseInstanceIDService");
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }
}
```

And this is how I logged my FCM token:

```
 String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
```

I think it's some conflict with google-api-client dependency with FCM. Can someone please point out, whats exactly going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> onTokenRefresh in FirebaseInstanceIdService is only called when a new token is generated. If your app was previously installed and generated a token then onTokenRefresh would not be called. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app to force the generation of a new token, this would cause onTokenRefresh to be called.

Hope it will resolve your issue.Happy coding.
Please see this link for the implementation of FCM.[FireBase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#set-up-firebase-and-the-fcm-sdk)

Comment: It doesn't help. I did it multiple times, but token is never generated.

Answer (score 0):

In my application tag in Manifest.xml, just removed ***tools:node="replace"*** and it started working.